# How can i create a text file from a pandas dataframe mixing two columns in an alternate form?

Tags: python, pandas, text-processing

Lets say i have two columns on a same huge dataframe (more than 1G of data) in pandas something like this (simplified):

df

```
A B
C D
```

and i want to create a text file with all data in the form below:

```
A
B
C
D
```

how would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways. You could use `.stack()` or `.melt()` or `.unstack()` or `pd.concat()`:

input:

```
0 1
A B
C D
```

#1:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.stack().reset_index(drop=True))
```

#2:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.melt().iloc[:,-1])
```

#3:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.unstack().reset_index(drop=True)) #keeps order as A, C, B, D
```

#4:

```
pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([df['0'],df['1']]).reset_index(drop=True)) #keeps order as A, C, B, D
```

output:

```
0
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: From these what do you think is the most efficient way? It is a huge data frame with more than 1G of data, also isnt it more efficient to iterate and stack while it writes to file instead of stacking everything beforehand?

Comment: @GlauberPrado I don't think flattening it would take very long prior to writing, but I am not sure. I think all methods would be similar. 1G of data is not that bad for pandas. Pandas starts to struggle after 10G+ from my experience, but it depends on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can save dataframe into text file using [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and

to save each column in new lines use `df.to_numpy().flatten()` convert dataframe to numpy array and then flatten it.

```py
np.savetxt("new.txt", df.to_numpy().flatten(), fmt='%s')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesnt apply to this cause im dealing with a lot of text data that span multiple lines so this would break the dataframe cutting the string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input guys, i did my own solution as the question is very specific, so i had to tailor it to my needs, but your responses pointed me in the right direction!

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('0.csv',header=None).loc[:, [3, 4]].stack().reset_index(drop=True))
f=open("0.txt","w+") # file name and mode
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  f.writelines(row[0])
f.close()
```